# why my .so file which is complied by boost.python and c++ header file failed?

Tags: python, c++, boost, cross-compiling, importerror

I successfully build some .so based on my c++ code, to let python to call.
but for this one, it's quite odd that I can't build in all ways I can think out.
Can anyone help me?

**exchang_info.h**

```
#ifndef EXCHANGE_INFO_H_
#define EXCHANGE_INFO_H_

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "define.h"
#include "info_type.h"
#include "order_side.h"
// #include "wrapstruct.h"

struct ExchangeInfo {
  InfoType::Enum type;
  char contract[MAX_CONTRACT_LENGTH];
  char order_ref[MAX_ORDERREF_SIZE];
  int trade_size;
  double trade_price;
  char reason[EXCHANGE_INFO_SIZE];
  OrderSide::Enum side;

  ExchangeInfo()
    : trade_size(0),
      trade_price(-1) {
  }

  void Show(std::ofstream &stream) const {
    stream.write((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
  }

  void ShowCsv(FILE* stream) const {
    /*  
    char time_s[32];
    snprintf(time_s, sizeof(time_s), "%ld.%ld", time.tv_sec, time.tv_usec);
    double time_sec = atof(time_s);
    */
    fprintf(stream, "%s,%s,%s,%d,%lf,%s,%s\n", InfoType::ToString(type),contract,order_ref,trade_size,trade_price,reason,OrderSide::ToString(side));
  }

  void Show(FILE* stream) const {
    timeval time;
    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    fprintf(stream, "%ld %06ld exchangeinfo %s |",
            time.tv_sec, time.tv_usec, order_ref);

    fprintf(stream, " %lf@%d %s %s %s\n", trade_price, trade_size, 
    InfoType::ToString(type), contract, OrderSide::ToString(side));
  }
};

#endif  //  EXCHANGE_INFO_H_
```

**wrapstruct.h**

```
#ifndef WRAPSTRUCT_H_
#define WRAPSTRUCT_H_

#include "exchange_info.h"
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(exchangeinfo) {
  class_<ExchangeInfo>("ExchangeInfo", init<>())
    .def_readwrite("type", &ExchangeInfo::type)
    .def_readwrite("contract", &ExchangeInfo::contract)
    .def_readwrite("order_ref", &ExchangeInfo::order_ref)
    .def_readwrite("trade_size", &ExchangeInfo::trade_size)
    .def_readwrite("trade_price", &ExchangeInfo::trade_price)
    .def_readwrite("reason", &ExchangeInfo::reason)
    .def_readwrite("side", &ExchangeInfo::side);
    //.def("Show", &ExchangeInfo::ShowCsv);
  enum_<InfoType::Enum>("InfoType")
    .value("Uninited", InfoType::Uninited)
    .value("Acc", InfoType::Acc)
    .value("Rej", InfoType::Rej)
    .value("Cancelled", InfoType::Cancelled)
    .value("CancelRej", InfoType::CancelRej)
    .value("Filled", InfoType::Filled)
    .value("Pfilled", InfoType::Pfilled)
    .value("Position", InfoType::Position)
    .value("Unknown", InfoType::Unknown);
  enum_<OrderSide::Enum>("OrderSide")
    .value("Buy", OrderSide::Buy)
    .value("Sell", OrderSide::Sell);
};

#endif //  WRAPSTRUCT_H_
```

**Complie command:**

```
g++ -std=c++11 -FPIC -shared wrapstruct.h -o exchangeinfo.so
```

It can complie .so file out, but can't be imported by Python,
when I try to import `exchangeinfo`, the error comes out as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /root/lib-hft/include/exchangeinfo.so: invalid ELF header
```

It really bother me these days, can anyone help me? 
And do you have better tools I can use to wrap my c++ code for python to call?
Thank you

Comment: Try [python invalid elf header](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+invalid+elf+header). (The other common error I found was download of package for wrong OS but this is not probable in your case.)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but a directory named `include` might not be the best place to have a shared library in.

Comment: @Scheff I think i used x64 for both, and other so is good to run. Thanks anyway for your advice

Comment: By looking through the hit list (in my above link), I saw other possible errors as well. Might be worth a look...

Comment: @n.m. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -FPIC -shared wrapstruct.h -o exchangeinfo.so
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

## No.

You cannot compile a header file into object code. When you try, `gcc` creates a *precompiled header*, not any kind of object file.

```
% file exchangeinfo.so
exchangeinfo.so: GCC precompiled header (version 014) for C++
```

Other compilers may or may not do anything useful.

Either rename your file to `wrapstruct.cpp`, or create a new file so named with a single line

```
#include "wrapstruct.h"
```

and compile that. The first way is much prefered; `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` macro defines a variable, and such definitions are best not placed in headers.

---

In fact you can force gcc to treat a file with any extension as any sort of file; you can add `-x c++` flag and gcc will compile it as a C++ file, regardless of the extension, but this is *extremely* not recommended.

Comment: If I got your answer right, `g++` created a precompiled header _named_ `exchangeinfo.so`. However a precompiled header is encoded - it certainly has no ELF header (nor is it usable as shared object) and would explain the exposed import error obviously. (Wow.)